# How to make transparent alpha color of a cell datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell, background-color, transparent

I have a datagridview as below:

[image]

I would like to make background color of a cell datagridview about 20%, 50%,... transparent (not fully transparent), where there is a color in the background (i.e. Black, Purple, Gray,...)?

I have tried many ways but I am not able to do it:

```
private void CustomerDGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Black 20%
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            SetCellsTransparent(e.RowIndex, Color.Black, 0.2);
        }

        // Purple 50%
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            SetCellsTransparent(e.RowIndex, Color.Purple, 0.5);
        }

        // Gray 100%
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            SetCellsTransparent(e.RowIndex, Color.Gray, 1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}

public void SetCellsTransparent(int rowIdx, Color color, double transparency)
{
    //Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
    //Color color = Color.Red;
    //this.Rows[rowIdx].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = color;

    //this.Rows[rowIdx].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(50, color);

    var whiteness = 255 - Convert.ToInt32(transparency * 255);
    this.Rows[rowIdx].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, whiteness, whiteness); //Red

    this.ClearSelection();
}
```

Any tips on these will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an WPF or a basic form, you are working with ?

Comment: Sorry for not clearly explaining. This is a basic form, windows form application.

Comment: Have you tried Color.FromArgb(whiteness, color)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1hstcth9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have tried but it cannot :(

Answer (score 0):

After refer to the link below, I did it run well.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6502/Transparency-Tutorial-with-C-Part

I hope this is useful for anyone required!